# Why is GetHostEvidence<StrongName>() returning null instead of the expected StrongName?

Tags: c#, appdomain, strongname

I am putting together a simple (sandboxed) module system for an application that I am writing in order to allow loading and execution of 'modules' written by others (untrusted code) while locking down permissions (File.IO, etc) to minimize the risk of malicious code.

Based on the article: [How to: Run Partially Trusted Code in a Sandbox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/misc/how-to-run-partially-trusted-code-in-a-sandbox)

*In step 2: Sign the assembly:*

```cs
StrongName fullTrustAssembly = typeof(Sandboxer).Assembly.Evidence.GetHostEvidence<StrongName>();
```

I get the following error:

> System.ArgumentException: 'A null StrongName was found in the full trust assembly list.'

Further investigation, sure enough, `fullTrustAssembly` is in fact null, and digging a bit deeper the `.GetHostEvidence<StrongName>();` is the method that is returning null.

I have found a solution here (that works): [A null strongname was found in the full trust assembly list sandbox application](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/150cc452-366f-412d-ab7b-b0593f24355e/a-null-strongname-was-found-in-the-full-trust-assembly-list-sandbox-application?forum=csharpgeneral) that looks like:

```cs
StrongName fullTrustAssembly = new StrongName(
    new StrongNamePublicKeyBlob(typeof(Sandboxer).Assembly.GetName().GetPublicKey()),
    typeof(Sandboxer).Assembly.GetName().Name,
    typeof(Sandboxer).Assembly.GetName().Version);
```

However, the person that provided the answer to that question stated:

> Prior to .net framework 4.0, you could not obtain a strongName by calling GetHostEvidence. Change the version of your .net framework.

I am using .NET Framework 4.8, so according to that statement, and the original tutorial, the GetHostEvidence() should be working.

**1.  Why is `GetHostEvidence<StrongName>()` not working as per the original tutorial?**

**2.  What is the real difference between the two different methods of obtaining a signed StrongName above?**

**Bonus points**

Google has not been my friend with finding current implementations and tutorials to accomplish my task in this sandboxed module manager portion of my project.  Are there any good resources (besides the .NET documentation) that can give more detail to understanding how it all works?  Most of what I can find is way out of date (10+ years old).  Are there more current strategies for achieving this. (note: I have looked into `Managed Extensibility Framework (MEF)` and feel it's great for another separate part of the project I am working on, but seems like overkill for this part. I have also looked at `System.Addin` (MAF?) but all I can find is Web/ASP related information for that, to which most of it is also extremely outdated)

Answer (score 0):

@Aaron Murray

Did you sign your assembly which has the SandBox class? if not, you can try the instructions mentioned here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/how-to-sign-an-assembly-with-a-strong-name

If the assembly is not signed, then it is expected to have typeof(Sandboxer).Assembly.Evidence.GetHostEvidence() returning null.

the doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/misc/how-to-run-partially-trusted-code-in-a-sandbox is explicity mentioning the signing requirements in step #2

Thanks.

Comment: That was exactly what I missed.  The second link you gave (which was the tutorial I was working off of), was kind of vague with the "Sign the assembly that contains the hosting class".  I thought that was what the `StrongName fullTrustAssembly = typeof(Sandboxer).Assembly.Evidence.GetHostEvidence<StrongName>();` was doing.  Once I went into the assembly 'Properties' / 'Sign' and signed the assembly, the above line worked properly (as per your first link).  Now I have a better understanding I can research that more.  However why then does the 'workaround' work without signing?

Comment: Not sure why you created a second answer to the question, however, neither answer really explains why the workaround works for obtaining the `StrongName`.  I understand now the step I missed in actually signing the assembly (which was not clear by the tutorial), but now if I haven't signed it, why can I still get the StrongName if I haven't signed it?

Comment: You didn’t get the StrongName object from the assembly.  You just created a StrongName object using the constructor which is not the same thing. This is not guaranteed to have this nicely work later when really needed to match the running assembly.

Comment: I removed the second answer as you pointed out. I didn’t mean to have it as a second answer.